# Merge with JPA not setting FK id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables with a relation composed of 2 columns, my first entity is:

```
public class NfCabeca implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "nf_cabeca_sequencial_seq", sequenceName = "nf_cabeca_sequencial_seq", schema = "mobile", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "nf_cabeca_sequencial_seq")
    @Column(name = "sequencial", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long sequencial;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @MapsId("nf_cabeca_id")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "sequencial" , referencedColumnName="nf_cabeca"), 
        @JoinColumn(name= "protocolo", referencedColumnName="protocolo")})
    private NFeProtocolo protocolo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "nf_cabeca_id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<NFeProtocolo> protocolos = new ArrayList<NFeProtocolo>();

 public void setProtocolo(NFeProtocolo protocolo) {
    this.protocolo = protocolo;
    protocolos.remove(protocolo);
    protocolo.setNf_cabeca_id(this);
    protocolos.add(protocolo);
  }
}
```

And my second entity is:

```
public class NFeProtocolo implements Serializable {



/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2092981840170296102L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "nf_cabeca" , referencedColumnName="sequencial", updatable = false)
    private NfCabeca nf_cabeca_id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "protocolo", length = 100)
    private String protocolo;

    @Column(name = "operacao", length = 15, nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private NFeProtocoloOperacao operacao;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "data_hora", length = 29, nullable = false)
    private Date dataHora;

    @Column(name = "status", length = 10)
    private String status;
}
```

The problem is when I set the `NFeProtocolo` inside `NFCabeca`

```
NFeProtocolo nFeProtocolo = new NFeProtocolo(protocolo, operacao, dataProtocolo, status);
nFeProtocolo.setNf_cabeca_id(nf);

nf.setProtocolo(nFeProtocolo);
merge(nf);
```

And I get an error:

> error message saying the column nf_cabeca cannot be set to null

It really can't, but what am I doing wrong on setting the `nf_cabeca` value?
When a watch the object nFeProtocolo, it does not has nf_cabeca_id exposed.

Protocolos content:

> [NFeProtocolo [protocolo=333170000339533, operacao=CRIACAO, dataHora=Wed Aug 09 09:19:11 BRT 2017, status=100]]

why is it not setting the nf_nf_cabeca_id outside?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was create a

```
public void setProtocolos(List<NFeProtocolo> protocolos) {
    this.protocolos = protocolos;
}
```

On NfCabeca and change nf_cabeca_id on NfeProtocolo to

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "nf_cabeca")
private NfCabeca nf_cabeca_id;
```